# How to convert from text to object in Java

Tags: java, file, object, oop, parsing

```
public void loadFromFile() {
    System.out.println("Loading books...");
    FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    try {
        fileInput = new FileInputStream("books.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileInput);
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.format("%-5s %-45s %-10s", "Id", "Name", "Price");
            System.out.println();
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("(empty)");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("File not found");
    } finally {
        try {
            fileInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // TODO: your code here
}
```

[i have a .txt file with the requirement a program reads it and parses it into object. Each line is an object including attributes id, name and price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzfBw.png)

how can I parse text to object

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static final class Book {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

}

public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Book> books = readMovies(new File("a.txt"));
}

private static List<Book> readMovies(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.id = scan.nextInt();

            String line = scan.nextLine().trim();
            int pos = line.indexOf("  ");
            book.name = line.substring(0, pos).trim();
            book.price = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(pos + 1).trim());
            books.add(book);
        }

        return books;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! (    1 Think big and Grow rich                            10.95)  can you split this? I need them to become each property in an object from a text file. id: 1, name : think..., price: 10.95. your code seems that not work in this case

Comment: From your picture it is not clear how the three columns are separated. Is it by TAB? Or do you have fixed column widths? Or what? Without this knowledge it's impossibel for us to help how you can split the three columns.

Answer (score 0):

// this code can help you, happy to help

import java.io.*;
public class FileTextCheck {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    User u1 = new User("Sudhakar", 27, "Male");
    User u2 = new User("Richa", 25, "Female");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/orange/Desktop/myfile.txt"));
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(u1);
        oos.writeObject(u2);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/orange/Desktop/myfile.txt"));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        User pr1 = (User) ois.readObject();
        User pr2 = (User) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(pr1.toString());
        System.out.println(pr2.toString());

        ois.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    User(String name, int age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name:" + name + "\nAge: " + age + "\nGender: " + gender;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks! but it seems that you misunderstood my question. Have you seen the image on the description under code?. i just need convert line by line to object, not just read them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse any type of text to a java object. The text should be in JSON format. You can parse JSON string to java object using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.